# How to characterise a UV lamp

Tags: experimental-physics, experimental-technology

I'm trying to characterise a deuterium lamp. It looks like a light bulb. Characterise in the sense of number of photons for wavelength (normalisation of the output spectral range).

The energy zone that I'm interested in is from 7 to 10eV.  (170 - 120nm)

I'd like to know the intensity and the wavelength of the light. I have a diffraction grating that I can put in front of the bulb.

I can't find a commercial spectrometer or detector that'll go this high.

My safety glasses are rated to above 10eV and everything goes on in a light sealed box.

Any ideas?

Comment: 'Characterize' covers a lot of sins. What exactly do you care to measure? Total luminosity? In some band? Relative spectrum? Absolute spectrum? Pyrometry suggests itself, but you'll need to know the emmisivity in that band, and such instruments aren't exactly run if the mill stuff.

Comment: A thin silicon detector with very thin glass on top should do just fine for detecting paired with the grating (and you need to check the grating for performance at that wavelength anyway). Getting absolute intensity, well that is a different problem.

Comment: A thermopile would be the usual detector; as long as it's reasonably black, the response should be good.   Not certain, though, if air is really transparent at that part of the spectrum.

Comment: @dmckee - added details of what I meant by characterise. I want the number of photons for each wavelength. Some commercial options offer a relative comparison.

Comment: @JonCuster - glass is totally absorbing (99.9%+) at anything above 6eV.

Comment: Not if there is only 10nm or so. Folks take that in to account designing deep uv diodes. Still, a PMT might work better for you.

Comment: @JonCuster, Photomultiplier tubes were the original idea but can't find a commercial one which'll up to roughly 100nm.

Comment: So you want to measure a spectrum and you want the absolute normalization. The latter is the harder part. And worse if you really mean that you want to count photons. Just getting the absolute power is a problem in bolometery (I misspoke before, I'm for ever getting pyrometers and bolometers mixed up, don't know why), but counting photons means confronting the QE of some single-photon detector in a unusual band.

Comment: @dmckee - yes. Its quite essential for the experiment, but it must've been done. Some people in literature quite energy values quite accurately for this range and above 10eV (but down explain how). Now, I think some Cs-Te PMTs exist, but can't find anyone who makes them, nor can I think of any better ideas. Some sort of material which could relatively measure (without increasing some sort of passive absorption - so couldn't be made from glass or quartz) but at some point have a reference with which I could measure with our spectrometer might work - but not sure if this even exists.